# Render user message and response only after clicking button

Tags: angularjs, timeout

I'm building a small chat app that simulates a conversation based on a few pre-defined messages and responses that are triggered by the user. When the user selects a persons name from the list, a message will appear. When the user types a message, it isn't supposed to show until the send button is clicked. After the user has sent their response, the application should then send the pre-defined response from the messages array after 2 seconds.

**The controller with directives**

```
var chatApp = angular.module("chatApp",['firebase']);

chatApp.controller("chatController",function($scope, $firebaseArray){
  var myUsers = new Firebase('https://chat-4477b.firebaseio.com/users');
   $scope.users = $firebaseArray(myUsers);
    $scope.messages = [{
        user:"aleksandra",
        message:"Aleksandra: this is aleksandras message",
        response:"a response from aleksandra",
        showDetails: false
      },
      {
        user:"evan",
        message:"Evan: this is evan message",
        response:"a response from evan",
        showDetails: false
      },
      {
        user:"tom",
        message:"Tom: this is toms message",
        response:"a response from tom",
        showDetails: false
      },
      {
        user:"jarid",
        message:"Jarid: this is jarids message",
        response:"a response from jarid",
        showDetails: false
      }];
      $scope.sendMessage = function(response){
        $scope.response = [];
        $scope.response.push(response);
        console.log(response);
      };
});

chatApp.directive("usersList", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: false,
        template: "<p>Users</p>"+
            "<ol class='list-unstyled animated fadeInDown'>"+
              "<li ng-repeat='message in messages'>"+
                "<a ng-click='toggleDetails(message)'>{{message.user}}</a>"+
              "</li>"+
            "</ol>"
        ,
        link: function(scope) {
          scope.toggleDetails = function(message)
          {
            angular.forEach(scope.messages, function(value, key){
              if(message != value)
                value.showDetails = false;
            });
            message.showDetails =  !message.showDetails;
          }

        }
    }

});

chatApp.directive("messagesList", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: false,
        template: "<div class='panel panel-primary'>"+
            "<div class='panel-heading'>"+
                "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-comment'></span> Chat</div>"+
            "<div class='panel-body body-panel'>"+
              "<ol class='list-unstyled'>"+
                "<li ng-repeat='message in messages | filter:{showDetails:true}'>"+
                    "<p>{{message.message}}</p>"+
                "</li>"+
                "<p>Matt: {{response}}</p>"+
                "<p>{{messages.response}}</p>"+
              "</ol>"+
            "</div>"+
            "<div class='panel-footer clearfix'>"+
              "<form name='form'>"+
                "<input type='text' name='message' ng-model='response' class='form-control' />"+
                "<span class='col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12' style='margin-top: 10px'>"+
                    "<button class='btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block' id='btn-chat' ng-click='sendMessage(messages)' ng-disabled='!form.message.$dirty'>Send</button>"+
                "</span>"+
              "</form>"+
            "</div>"+
        "</div>"
        };
});
```

In the current state, the app is loading the message as it should, but when the user types a response, it automatically shows due to the `{{response}}` being set within the message box. I'm trying to get it to only show the response on click using:

```
$scope.sendMessage = function(response){
    $scope.response = [];
    $scope.response.push(response);
    console.log(response);
};
```

which should be triggered by: `ng-click='sendMessage(messages)'`

However, the current state is showing the message in the chat box before hitting submit, though it should be coming from the `$scope.response = [];` array on click.

I've tried using a timeout function like this:

```
  function chatApp($timeout, $scope){
      $scope.sendMessage = function(response){
        $timeout(function(){
        $scope.response = [];
        $scope.response.push(response);
        console.log(response);
      }, 2000);
    };
  }
```

but it isn't having any affect.

So to recap: The app loads with the current users name and an empty prompt. When the user clicks a name from the right, the name will show in the chat box, along with the predefined initial message. When the user enters a response, the response should **only** show in the chat history when the user hits the send button. Within that same function, there should be a timeout that triggers the pre-defined response to show after 2 seconds. I'm stuck on how to keep the response from showing until the user hits send, allowing the timeout function to run and show the predefined response afterward.

**Here is a plunker for the current state:** [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/upu3WqcWQ4kw45KqqDi7?p=preview)

Comment: Can you post the html?

Comment: @cYrixmorten - just updated question with full controller and directive code.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I needed to simplify the function like so and trigger the timeout right after the message is pushed to the response array.

```
$scope.sendMessage = function(){
      $scope.response.push($scope.chat);
      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.autoresponse = "This is a great app!";
      }, 3000);
  };
```